# Notification alerts on a call in android?

Tags: android, audio, notifications, call, vibration

when placing a call and I show a notification, just the icon appears in the bar, and the phone does not ring or vibrate.

How could this happen?

my code:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     int icon = R.drawable.icon;
     CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
     long when = System.currentTimeMillis ();

     Notification notification = new Notification (icon, tickerText, when);

     Context context = getApplicationContext ();
     CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
     CharSequence contentText = "My Message";
     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent (this, NotificationClic.class);
     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity (this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

     notification.setLatestEventInfo (context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
     notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
     notification.flags | = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

     mNotificationManager.notify (1, notification);
```

greatly appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
notification.setSound(sound);
```

You'll need to use the `NotificationBuilder` to build your `Notification` object, and then assign the parameters. Here's a basic example:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setContentTitle("Your Notification Title")
            .setContentText("Your Notification Text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .build();
```